# Capitalize **kerry James O'keeffe-martin** to **Kerry James O'Keeffe-Martin** in TypeScript and Java Script

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

How can I Capitalize name in Type script and Java Script
my input is like **kerry James O'keeffe-martin** to **Kerry James O'Keeffe-Martin**

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Is there ever a space between `O and '`?

Comment: These sorts of replacements are problematic, so don't use it for anything important.  Also, don't forget about "smart" quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace every letter after a word boundary with a capital letter using a regular expression with the replacement method:

```js
const inp = "kerry James O'keeffe-martin";
const res = inp.replace(/\b\w/g, m => m.toUpperCase());
console.log(res);
```